# Angular 13 - Clock timer display

Tags: javascript, angular, time

I have the following code to display time elapsed on screen:

```
  const counter = timer(0, 1000);

  ngOnInit(): void {
    counter.subscribe((val) => {
      this.time();
    });
  }

  time(): any {
    const date = new Date();
    const startDate = new Date(date.getUTCFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate() );
    const diffDate = new Date((date.getTime() - startDate.getTime()));
    let second: number | string = diffDate.getSeconds();
    let minute: number | string = diffDate.getMinutes();
    const hour: number | string = diffDate.getHours();
    if (second < 10) {
      second = '0' + second;
    }
    if (minute < 0) {
      minute = '0' + minute;
    }
    this.clock = hour + ':' + minute + ':' + second;
    console.log(this.clock);
  }
```

This code works, but always with a time difference of 5 hours. I could manually adjust the 5 hours, but that does not sound healthy for the application, so is there any way to get this time calculation correctly.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you describe what the code is supposed to do? Is it supposed to show the current date and time in UTC? Or client date and time?

Comment: @Nathan It is supposed to show the difference between the 2 times, assuming the two initial dates are using the same timezone.